# How to remove empty comma from string using JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, string

I want to remove empty commas from the string using JQuery.
Please see the attached images to see what i mean.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will remove all unnecessary commas in the text and update the text value:

```
$('.dyn-').text($('.dyn-').text().replace(/^,*|,(?=,)|,$/g, ''));
```

The regex is in three parts, seperated by `|`:

1. first part catches all the commas in the beginning of the string,
   since they come before a word, they are all unnecessary,
2. second part catches all commas followed by a comma, so only the last of the
   repeating commas will stay,
3. and third part catches a comma that is at the very end of the string, which is unnecessary.

Comment: could you please explain the regex?

Comment: @Anubhav i updated the answer to be more explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

i think it would be easier to get to the source that is causing you this trouble instead of trying it backwards.. 
their is a solution but why not trying to remove it from the beginning?

any chance to let us see the code?
maybe we could come up with the problem from the source.